# How can I conduct predictive analysis on a time series data?

Tags: python, model, regression, prediction, exploratory-data-analysis

[image: Please see this image]

I was trying to use predictive analysis to forecast future charge patterns over a period (months and years). The data has been cleaned to the level of analysis. The remaining part is the predictive part which involves time stamp. Month, year, and day of the week have been extracted for proper analysis. I have used different syntax doing this but didn't get positive result.

Comment: What result did you get instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[163], line 7
      4 y = df['Charging Duration (Minutes)']
      6 # Perform one-hot encoding for categorical variables
----> 7 encoder = OneHotEncoder(drop='first', sparse=False)
      8 X_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(X[['Month_un', 'Hour_pl', 'Day_of_week_pl']])
     10 # Combine one-hot encoded features with other numerical features

NameError: name 'OneHotEncoder' is not defined

Comment: i didn't get the step well, the prediction is most likely from Feb to Dec 2024 because there are datasets for the month Jan already. trying to predict for Feb to Dec